# Strange entity framework exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have very simple method and sometimes (probably under high load) it throws very weird exceptions.One of them

- The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION
- New request is not allowed to start because it should come with valid transaction descriptor
- The connection does not support MultipleActiveResultSets

Bellow you can see method and the stacks of the exceptions

```
        using (var context1 = cp.GetNewContext())
        {
           //some work here
             await context1.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        using (var context2 = cp.GetNewContext())
        {
            var entity = context2.Entities 
                .FirstOrDefault(e => e.ClassId == classId)
                          ?? context2.Entities.Add(new Entitity());

            entity.ClassId = classId;
            entity.Date = DateTime.UtcNow;

            context2.SaveChanges();
        }
     }
```

Could someone help me? Whre should I search?

Exceptions

- The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

  > System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5() at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1..GetEnumerator>b__0() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
- New request is not allowed to start because it should come with valid transaction descriptor

  > System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: New request is not allowed to start because it should come with valid transaction descriptor. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update() at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction) at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
- The connection does not support MultipleActiveResultSets

  > System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The connection does not support MultipleActiveResultSets. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.b__24(Task`1 result) at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.d__c.MoveNext() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.d__c.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.d__0`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.d__3d`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbExecutionStrategy.d__9`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.d__e.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyAsyncEnumerator`1.d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.d__5`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.d__1a`3.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at

Comment: What is `context` (I see only `context1` and `context2` variables)?

Comment: I see `var entity = context.Entities`, shouldn't that be: `var entity = context2.Entities`, and again after the `??` operator.

Comment: You pasted the MultipleActiveResultSets exception twice. One obvious question: is `MultipleActiveResultSets` enabled in the connection string? Another: which line throws the exception?

Comment: Please redo, there is still `?? context.`

Comment: Do you really need context1 to stay alive while context2 is working? Can't you close its `using` after `context1.SaveChangesAsync();`?

Comment: @GertArnold,MultipleActiveResultSets aren't enabled in the connection string

Comment: where is the transaction starting and ending? also.. why do you need two context object? it would create two connections to the database and transaction management would be difficult there depending upon how much of "some work" in both of them interleave

Comment: So you should probably enable MARS. Again: which line throws the exception? You have two separate transactions.